# typeorm: Impossible to retrieve a joined value

Tags: typescript, typeorm, many-to-one

I have the following config for an object:

```
export class Network {
  @PrimaryColumn({ name: "id" })
  id: string;

  @Column("text")
  url: string;

  @ManyToOne(
    type => User,
    user => user.users,
    { nullable: true, onDelete: "SET NULL", onUpdate: "CASCADE" }
  )  
  csm: User;

  get_data(): {} {
        return {
          id: this.id,
          url: this.url,
          csm: this.csm ? this.csm.id : null,
        };
      }
}
```

User is another class, which doesn't refer to networks
When I save my data, it works fine:
In my table, I have a column csmId which is fulfilled with the appropriate id of a user.
The program to fulfill those values looks like 
`my_network.csm=csm` where csm is a User object.
Now, when I try to retrieve my data with the function `get_data()`, the csm is always empty, not matter what. Other values are properly fulfilled
Can anyone help on that?
Many thanks

Comment: What is `this` in the `get_data()` function?

Comment: @noamsteiner: `this`is the network object. I changed my descritption to let you better understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was: adding eager (or lazy), so the join is automatically done